# Changes to the code are not getting reflected in Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, devise

I have started a project using Rails 3.0. I am using devise for the authentication. Devise includes links to signin and forgot password in the sign up page. These links are loaded by means of a partial.I did not need these links, so I removed them and reloaded the page, but still these links remain. I tried clearing the cache and trying in a different browser(Safari). I added a new field(name) in the form but even that is not getting reflected.Could you please help me out. Thanks

/app/views/users/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <p><%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :email %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></p>

  <p><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run a command that creates local copies of your devise views and edit them. Have you done this?

See http://github.com/plataformatec/devise

and scroll down to the views section.

If you have done this then it's probably something to do with the order things are being loaded, as in it should pick up your local views first and is picking up the ones in the gem instead.

Comment: Hey thanks... Actually I used the rails generate devise:views users before. Model name was User, so I thought I had to generate for the users.I should have used rails generate devise:views. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to restart the server? (That would be strange, but possible).

To be sure that your problem is really the problem with caching in the browser side, use a wget, or better: write a functional test.

Have you used caching in your controllers?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the server but its still does not change. I am just using the controller that comes with the devise and it is not using caching